# Does Improved Knockdown reduce the multi-attack penalty?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, multiple-attack-penalty, critical-success

The Improved Knockdown fighter and mauler feat modifies the Knockdown feat action, specifically

> You can dash your foe to the ground with a single blow. When you use Knockdown, instead of making a Strike followed by a Trip, you can attempt a single Strike. If you do and your Strike hits, instead of rolling a check for your Trip attempt, you automatically apply the critical success effect of a Trip. If you used a two-handed melee weapon for the Strike, you can use the weapon's damage die size instead of the regular die size for the damage from a critical Trip.

Notably, this doesn't say you make a Strike followed by a Trip any more - does this mean taking Improved Knockdown reduces the attack penalty "cost" of the knockdown action from two attacks to only one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You Attempt a Single Strike

[Knockdown](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=372) has this line at the end about the multiple attack penalty:

> **Both attacks count toward your multiple attack penalty**, but the penalty doesn't increase until after you've made both of them.

Increasing your multiple attack penalty with each attack is the [default rule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=322) for abilities with multiple attacks, but not increasing the penalty until the end would be the exception.

With Improved Knockdown you don't make two attacks, instead making a single Strike with the effects of a critically successful [Trip](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=40) attempt.

> When you use Knockdown, instead of making a Strike followed by a Trip, you can attempt a single Strike.

> **Critical Success** The target falls and lands prone and takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage.

Only one attack is made so your multiple attack penalty only increases once.